# Closure of subset of the continuous functions from [0,1] to R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Prove that $$M = \left\{ f \in \textit{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})\ |\ \int_{0}^{1/2}f(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1f(t)dt = 1\right\} \subset \textit{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}) $$ is closed.
$$$$ By way of contradiction, suppose that M is not closed.  So $\forall \{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq M, \text{such that} f_k \rightarrow f \in \textit{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \wedge f \notin M$.

Now, we have, for that $f \notin M$, $\int_{0}^{1/2}f(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1f(t)dt \not= 1$, so $$\int_{0}^{1/2}\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t)dt \not= 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1/2}f_n(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1f_n(t)dt\right) \not= 1\ \textbf{(1)}$$ but for all naturals numbers we have $\int_{0}^{1/2}f_n(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1f_n(t)dt = 1$. Reaching the contradiction.

Am i allow in **(1)** to bring out the limit? This is my only concern. Although, my reasoning is that $n$ does not depend on the integral sign. If its okey, why is that the case?

Comment: $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, so the sequence of integrals tends to the integral of $f$. You don't need to prove by contradiction here, a direct argument will work in exactly the same way. (but would look better)

Comment: Whatever "$n$ does not depend on the integral sign" means, it is not sufficient to prove what you need.

Comment: " $\forall \{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \textit{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}), \text{such that} f_k \rightarrow f \wedge f \notin M$" should be replaced with  $\exists\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq M, \text{such that} f_k \rightarrow f \wedge f \notin M.$

Comment: A shorter proof is: $M=F^{-1}(\{1\}),$ where the linear map $F: f\mapsto\int_{0}^{1/2}f(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1f(t)dt$ is continuous since $|F(f)|\le\|f\|.$

Comment: It would be helpful to identify the intended topology of $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ or (alternatively) the criterion for convergence of a sequence of these continuous real functions on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions on compact set are bounded and convergence is uniform, So $|f_n(x)| \leq B$, $\forall x \in [0,1]$ and $n$ and $g(x) = B$ is integrable and hence you can apply dominated convergence theorem to bring limit in and out of integral. Check dominated convergence theorem.

Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem